# How can I get around the error "SELECT statement is not allowed in user-defined functions" in Synapse (Azure Datawarehouse)?

Tags: function, azure-synapse

I have an Azure Synapse Data Warehouse running on a dedicated SQL Pool so it can store tables and do analysis.  I have a function that works in Azure SQL and I copied it to my Synapse warehouse.  It returns either 'yes' or 'no' as a string depending on whether or not the value we are feeding in appears in the table - the function is copied below

```
create function [dbo].[fnSourceTableExists] (
    @SchemaName sysname,
    @TableName sysname
)
returns nvarchar(3)

as
begin
    return case when exists (select TABLE_NAME from [SomeSchema].[Company_Tables] where TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName and @TableName = ObjectName)  then 'Yes' else 'No' end
end
```

It gives the error "SELECT statement is not allowed in user-defined functions"  I have several functions similar to this which involve getting a single value from a select query.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the following official Microsoft documentation, Azure synapse analytics gives an error when the body of the function contains a `SELECT` query.

[CREATE FUNCTION (Azure Synapse Analytics) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7#arguments:%7E:text=are%20not%20allowed.-,function_body,-Series%20of%20Transact)

Looking at the user-defined function that you have, one viable option would have been to use `Stored Procedures` instead. But `Stored Procedures` in Azure synapse have certain drawbacks, among which one of them is that it does not support the usage of `RETURN` statement. Refer to the following official documentation to know about all the drawbacks of Stored Procedures in Azure synapse analytics.

[Using stored procedures - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-stored-procedures#:%7E:text=temporary%20tables.-,Limitations,-There%20are%20some)

Since your user-defined functions have only a single select statement and there seems to be no proper workaround, it would be better to execute the select statements as is instead of using user-defined functions. If you have access to SQL Server Management Studio, you can use `Dedicated SQL endpoint` along with the `SQL authentication` to connect to data warehouse to SSMS and work with user-defined functions.